# firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() doesn't support Timestamp data type

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
 async createUser(uid: string, email: string) {
    await this.afs.doc<UserProfileModel>(FirestoreDbConstant.USER_PROFILES + `/${uid}`).set({
      email,
      createdDate: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    });
  }
```

This model works

```
export interface UserProfileModel {
    email: string;
    createdDate?: firebase.firestore.FieldValue;
}
```

But Why I cannot use `Timestamp` here like so?

```
import { Timestamp } from '@firebase/firestore-types';

export interface UserProfileModel {
    email: string;
    createdDate?: Timestamp;
}
```

Then it gives this error:

> (property) UserProfileModel.createdDate?: Timestamp Type 'FieldValue'
>   is missing the following properties from type 'Timestamp': seconds,
>   nanoseconds, toDate, toMillists(2739) user-profile.model.ts(11, 5):
>   The expected type comes from property 'createdDate' which is declared
>   here on type 'UserProfileModel'

The problem here is I need to use `toDate()` on the template. But it doesn't work with the  `createdDate?: firebase.firestore.FieldValue;`

```
<p>{{invitedEvent.startDatetime.toDate() | amDateFormat: 'MMM DD'}}</p>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can see from the [JavaScript API documentation for serverTimestamp()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue.html#servertimestamp):

> serverTimestamp(): FieldValue
>
> Returns a sentinel used with set() or update() to include a
>   server-generated timestamp in the written data.
>
> Returns FieldValue

It doesn't return a Timestamp type.  It returns a FieldValue, whose value is actually just a placeholder for a special value that tell the server to generate the timestamp.  The client doesn't generate this timestamp at all, since we can't trust the client device's clock.

This means you can't really use the same model for reading and writing records that use server timestamps.  On the way in, it will be a FieldValue.  On the way out (when you query the document), it will be a Timestamp.

Comment: Hmm... That means the only solution here is `any` no?

Comment: If you want.  Or use two different models as I suggested, one for reading and one for writing.

Answer (score 5):

This might be better than 'any' or duplicating models :

`lastModified: Timestamp | FieldValue;`

Comment: Sometimes it's necessary to typecast the values when you set them, as the Typescript compiler can sometimes be confused, and needs help knowing what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for this is to define your own interface that partially extends both Timestamp and FieldValue

```
    export interface MyTimestamp extends Partial<FieldValue>, Partial<Timestamp>
    {
      isEqual: (other: any) => boolean;
      valueOf: () => any;
    }
```

Then you can set your timestamp props to:

```
    export interface UserProfileModel {
        email: string;
        createdDate?: MyTimestamp;
    }
```

You'll then get proper types for both writing and reading to firestore

The one caveat is that all props and functions are now optional so if you want to call `toDate()` on Timestamp for example you'll need to use `?`
`user.createdDate?.toDate?.()`

Writing:

```
user.createdDate = FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
```

Reading:

```
user.createdDate?.toDate?.();
```